# Android Wear 2.0 on swipe back close the app

Tags: android, swipe, exit, kill, android-wear-2.0

I need to know how we can close the application on swipe left in Android Wear 2.0.
It's a standalone application.

1. On swipe left which method we can override(If I want to do any other process)
2. what is the method for close the application - which we have like on mobile android `this.finishAffinity();`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

For and `Activity` you don't have to do anything, as stated in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/ui/exit.html)

> An activity automatically supports swipe-to-dismiss. Swiping an
>   activity from left to right results in dismissal of the activity, and
>   the app navigates down the back stack.

If you use a `Fragment` you need to wrap it in a [SwipeDismissFrameLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wear/widget/SwipeDismissFrameLayout.html). For more details about how to do that, or how to handle other edge cases, have a look at the documentation referenced above.

Comment: Is it possible to show the previous Fragment behind the Fragment that is being swiped away? So just like how it works with Activities.

Comment: Fragments work the same way as Activities. What you are describing should be the default behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried out the `SwipeDismisFrameLayout` but the issue is the animation when swiping. When you start swiping away the Fragment you can't see the Fragment behind it. The Fragment appears when you stop swiping (because the Fragment is popped in `onDismissed` callback). So my question is, how can the previous Fragment be drawn behind the 'fragment that is being swiped away'. I'm using `replace` for the Fragment transaction.

Comment: I see. You might want to post this as a separate question. Unfortunately I don't have a quick answer for you.